# Create an interface in SharePoint that will make a custom view when the user selects key words

Tags: view, custom, metadata

I was thinking of adding something similar to a shopping Cart that will allow visitors select metadata and create a library or list view on the fly. It could be similar to a library metadata navigation filter but on the main page.
Thanks for any help on this.